# Android no menu item show in layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, menu

I can see in menu design have picture like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHcFZ.jpg

But when I switch to layout design

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NrSO.jpg

I cannot see the menu anymore.

I already check for menu setting

1. make a onCreateOptionsMenu
2. set menu/main.xml
3. xmlns:tools / tools:context

But it still have no menu bar in there.
The code is below:

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if(id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Layout/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jason.web_control.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/playPauseButton"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
            android:id="@+id/mousePad"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

menu/menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.jason.web_control.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Check which theme you are using,,may be you are using noactionbar theme

Comment: I tried your code and can able to achieve by extending ActionBarActivity in that and add appcompactV7 jar in that ....if you are getting solution update that and i will post the code..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Please include this line in your code   *setHasOptionsMenu(true);*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the activity is not extended in fragment.
I can't call the setHasOptionMenu in onCreate() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
    What I did was                                                                                        

    public MoviesFragment() {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
and need to override                                                                                          
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {

        }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```